# Celery in Django, How can I find all the tasks?

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I am using Celery in Django. I want to find all the tasks and show them in the webpage. But I can't find all the tasks. I can only find finished tasks through `djcelery.models.TaskMeta`. Where can I find the pending or running tasks. Or is there a easy way to show tasks in the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

you can use  " celery -A proj events "  commands to see the tasks ,
more details go with 
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/monitoring.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`your_celery_app.control.inspect()`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#inspecting-workers) to query information from the workers. See Celery documentation for available commands.